# Initializing the input form in AngularJS using value from scope variable

Tags: angularjs

How do I initialize a form to values from other `$scope` variable in AngularJS?
I know that I have to use `ng-init` to achieve that but instead of initializing it to values I have to initialize that to value in the variable.

I have `$scope.User` containing all the details of the user, so when the data comes back I want that to fed into respective fields. For example `$scope.User.FirstName` gets fed into FirstName input field.

```
<label>FirstName:</label>
<input type="text" id="FirstName" required ng-model="newUser.FirstName" ng-init="newUser.FirstName='User.FirstName'"/>
```

Comment: don't use `ng-init`, this is a job for a controller.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML element has to be defined as below.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
```

Inside your angular controller, the JS code will be as below,

```
$scope.firstname = $scope.User.FirstName;
```

This will ensure that textbox will have a value displayed

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="User.firstname ">
<input type="text" ng-model="User.lastName ">
//other html elements
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.User= {
  firstname : 'my first name',
  lastName : 'my last name',
  //..other data
}
```